# Do I need a disc drive to install Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

My computer doesn't have a disc drive and I am unsure how to continue installing without one.

Comment: Please clarify, if you don't have a CD/DVD drive or you don't have a hard disk. **Edit the question accordingly.**

Comment: You can install if you have a usb thumb drive. See KamikazeCZ's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean a CD/DVD disk drive. Then it's possible and easy to do. Read this [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick).

However, if you do not have a hard disk drive, you can still install the OS *on* a USB stick (not to be confused with installing *from* it) . I wouldn't recommend this though.

Comment: Please, look again at what I wrote. The second paragraph is about installing the OS *on* the USB stick, not *from* it.

Comment: I stand corrected. I didn't consider a computer with **no** hard drive at all. I had one of those once, but it was a TRS-80 Model 1!